# C# Property get set doesn't set a value

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I've searched on Google and Stack Overflow for this problem I'm having.
Unfortunately I'm not able to find the correct answer to my problem.

First-off I'll be showing my Classes and App.config.

**Class: Form1 : Form**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Database db = new Database();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        db.Test();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db.MdfConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MDFConnection"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

**Class: Database**

```
class Database
{
    private string _mdfConnectionString;

    public string MdfConnectionString
    {
        get { return this._mdfConnectionString; }
        set { this._mdfConnectionString = value; }
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_mdfConnectionString);
    }
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MDFConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database\AutoFill.mdf;Integrated Security=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

In my Class **Database.cs** I've got an **MessageBox.Show(_mdfConnectionString);** that will show the private string ( backing field ) but, for some odd reason the **_mdfConnectionString** is always null.

I've declared on my Class **Form1 : Form** that it needs to load the connection string in my App.config.

Not forgetting to mention that **ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MDFConnection"].ConnectionString;** itself returns a value so that's not the issue here.

Hope somebody can help me on this problem.

**EDIT 1**

Changed the code to make it more clear for people. Also the ExecuteQuery isn't important so I made a simple method in Database.cs Class calling a Message Box.

Also the Executable and Exe.config are inside the same folder while executing.

Comment: First thing to learn about is automatically implemented properties - you can get rid of your field declaration, and rewrite your property as `public string MdfConnectionString { get; set; }`

Comment: Have you debugged into the code to see whether your `Form1_Load` method is actually called? Have you checked that it's hooked up appropriately to the event? Are you perhaps using `db` before the form has finished loading?

Comment: Form_Load1 is being called, used Message Box and breakpoints. I'll try to use the Auto-Implement Properties.

Comment: Not really convenient the "Auto-Implement Property" for me cause the Database constructor needs a value when making an instance and that's what i'm trying to avoid here.

Comment: Your command about automatically-implemented properties really doesn't make sense - you can replace your current property with an automatically-implemented one, use the property within the `Database` class instead of referring to the field, and everything else will be the same. It won't fix the issue, but it's worth knowing about just to simplify your code.

Comment: How/where are you calling ExecuteQuery(...) ?

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar it's being called from public Form1 but it has a breakpoint below messagebox so it stops right there and shows no value what so ever.

Comment: Disregard everything else. Are you sure ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MDFConnection"].ConnectionString; is actually retrieving the value from your app.config? Output this in a messagebox instead of the property

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry I was talking about the constructor that needs a parameter when i'm using the auto-implement property. But it seems it also doesn't need one if I keep `private string _mdfConnectionString;` but returns a warning that it's never used. Anyway thanks for letting me know, it's really cleans up a bit ;)

Comment: I have just implemented your code exactly as you have posted it and it works fine.

Comment: @Roemy: It's still unclear where the constructor comes in. You can set a property from a constructor too... and making the property an automatically-implemented one certainly *doesn't* force you to have a constructor parameter. What error did you get without the parameter? Are you certain that you've made `Database` a class rather than a struct? (If it were a struct, some of this would make a bit more sense... but it would be a bad design decision.) It would really help if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem here.

Comment: You're calling ExecuteQuery in **public Form1** as in the constructor?

Comment: Do you try to break the `setter` in the property to see if anywhere else overwrite the value in the call stack?

Comment: @CathalMF That is the weird part, I've copied some code from a earlier project that is working fine and using part of this code on my new project and it doesn't work. That's why i'm out of ideas and options.

Comment: @Roemy Are you 100% certain that the ConfigurationManager is retreving the string from the file? Is the file in the same directory as your exe and has the correct name? <exename>.exe.config?

Comment: It is not clear to me why everybody is using `ConfigurationManager` with some possibly missspelled string, instead of simply using `Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString`,  managing the connection string using the Settings tab in the project properties as a setting of type connection string...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I'll try looking into that. Also My post has been edited

Comment: In your edit, the Constructor is triggerd BEFORE the load. so the connectionstring will be NULL when triggering the db.test() indeed, like I said in my answer below.

Comment: @Cageman Thnx, seems I was doing that all the time!

Comment: I would like to thank you all for helping me I'll post my resolve Thanks@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an exact answer, but there are a couple of questions I would be asking myself in the same situation.

1. Is the connection string actually gained? i.e. split the solution up a bit for debugging add a breakpoint on myConn as shown below.

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   {

   var myConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MDFConnection"].ConnectionString;
   db.MdfConnectionString = myConn;

   }
2. Your current solution by design allows the datatbase class to be used without a connection string. Would it be better to put the connection into the constructor to eliminate the potential bug? E.g.

   public class Database
   {

   private string _mdfConnectionString;

   public Database(string conn)

   {

   _mdfConnectionString = conn;

   }

   ...

   }

You may then want to construct it on the form load.

3. With web stuff, sometimes you are not working with the instance you think you are working with. If all else fails, you could try changing the class to a singleton, but the Dependency Injection style should be better.

EDIT - Following your edit, I believe you are now calling Test before the form load. Please try point 2 (inject the connectionstring into the constructor) and then you know you can't have an instance of the class without a connection string. I have tried your class in a console and it is fine, so the problem is highly likely to be the load order. DI would fix this.

Comment: I was always told not to use a singleton of a databaseinstance, especially not in a webinstance.

Comment: @hockeyJ 1. Its gained. Also when doing this: `db.MdfConnectionString = "Test Weeeeee"` still results in null. 2. I'll close that gap later on so it'll fail when connection string not defined, any thanks for showing me :)

Comment: @Roemy - if you have the connection, then try passing it in the constructor. Then you should not be able to have an instance of the class without a connection string. Cageman - I agree with not using Singletons in the final product. It was meant as investigational help in the case the Roemy is not accessing the instance he is expecting. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Whene is the methode being called?
Yust looking to your code it likes in the constructor, so initializise the string in the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
     db.MdfConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MDFConnection"].ConnectionString;
     InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: I've tried that already and that doesn't work either, value remains null

Comment: Like HockeyJ said (point 1) check if the connectionstring has been fetched on loading.

Answer (score 0):

**Form1 : Form**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Database db = new Database();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //db.Test(); // Removed!
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db.MdfConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MDFConnection"].ConnectionString;
        db.Test(); // Returns a value! :D
    }
}
```

Seems I was loading my methods before loading the form itself.

Comment: Please note that usually you should not write an answer yourself. Instead, accept the answer that helped you, maybe comment on which part of the answer helped you. The thing is that this is not a forum, so the answers will not stay in the same order all the time.